# Stolen SQL server memory

Tags: sql-server

Can someone explain how to reduce *stolen* SQL server memory and reason for taking more memory in SQL server.

Though I have capped max memory to 20 GB out of 26 GB still I see stolen SQL server memory is taking more than 13 GB. How do I reduce it?

Comment: my total server memory and target server memory shows 18gb.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It's hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Are you referring to how SQL Server will greedily eat up as much memory as it thinks it needs and then hold on to it?  The only way to get it to release that memory is to restart SQL Server, AFAIK.  If that's what you're asking, please clarify your question though.

Comment: My Total memory is 25 GB and SQL max mem is 18 GB.

Comment: While collecting the counters. Total and Target server memory is 18 GB and Stolen Memory shows as 13 GB.